# OpenWrt- Llamar desde un script con xhr.get a un servidor lua y recibir una variable como respuesta

Tags: lua

La idea es la siguiente, con una llamada desde el script en html realizar una llamada al servidor que me retorne una variable.

LA llamada seria tal que

```
XHR.get('<%=REQUEST_URI%>',  { one : '1' }, function(x,info) {
        console.log(info);
    });
```

y la respuesta seria según lo que he podido encontrar

```
function parse_gateway()
 local one = luci.http.formvalue("one")
 local fileContent = {
    content = "sample1",
    find = "sample2"
 }
 luci.http.prepare_content("application/json")
 luci.http.write_json(fileContent) 
end
```

Pero esto siempre me produce un 
 **eof expected near 'end'** si lo pongo en el htm. La mayoría de la información la he obtenido de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304850/how-to-pass-array-in-xhr-get-request-of-luci-openwrt) pero esta muy poco concreto y como prueba copiando y pegando sus códigos no me funcionan.

**Actualizo, milagrosamente ha funcionado (compila y parece que hace algo), lo único que la respuesta no llega la información correcta (llega un null por consola)**

Answer (score 1):

Vale ya he conseguido arreglarlo bien, lo primero, el problema es que si realizas la llamada como viene ahí a Request_URI, te llamas a ti mismo y el problema es que te mezcla el html con el json entonces te produce un error al parsear.

la solución que yo he preferido es  1º crear una nueva vista contigua a la mía

```
XHR.get('<%=REQUEST_URI%>'+'<%:/service%>',  { one : '1' }, function(x,info) {
        console.log(info);
 });
```

y 2º en esta vista realizar lo siguiente (service.htm)

```
<%
function parse_gateway()
    local one = luci.http.formvalue("one")
    local fileContent = {
        content = "sample1",
        find = "sample2"
    }
    luci.http.prepare_content("application/json")
    luci.http.write_json(fileContent)
end
if luci.http.formvalue("one") == "1" then
    parse_gateway()
end -%>
```

Este ultimo if es importante para que tipo de respuesta deseas. 
Para la creación de la vista solo hay que seguir los tutoriales pero es algo así :

```
entry({"admin", "patatin", "patatan", "service"}, template("patatin/service"), _("Service"), 90)
```